# If the girth of a $2k$-regular graph $G$ is larger than the diameter of a tree $T$ with $k$ edges, then $G$ is decomposed into copies of $T$

Tags: graph-theory, trees, regular-graph

I want to prove that ‘If the girth of a $2k$-regular graph $G$ is larger than the diameter of a $k$-edge tree $T$, then $G$ is covered by edge-disjoint copies of $T$.’
I tried several ways to solve this problem:

1. Use the fact ‘If $\delta(G)\ge k$, $G$ contains a $k$-edge tree as a subgraph.’
2. Consider the tree-packing and tree-covering problem.
3. Create a proper algorithm.

I searched papers about this problem, and I found that Haggkvist proved it.
Here is the reference: page 130 of [Decompositions of complete bipartite graphs](https://books.google.co.kr/books?hl=ko&lr=&id=4QsLL8thoU0C&oi=fnd&pg=PA115&dq=Decompositions%20of%20complete%20bipartite%20graphs&ots=z8uG1Wy85l&sig=RWEW6V7R8MEKXXM_-smqcBHcgW0#v=onepage&q=Decompositions%20of%20complete%20bipartite%20graphs&f=false).
But unfortunately, he said the manuscript containing his proof is not formally published.
So the only thing I know is this statement is true, and Haggkvist used it as a theorem.
But I cannot still find nice proof or strategy about it.
Would you help me?

Comment: I think there is a typo or a missing hypothesis.  Perhaps you want $k \geq 2$?  For example, the three-cycle (boundary of a triangle) has girth three, but is not edge-disjointly covered by paths of length two.

Comment: Hmm.  The one-skeleton of the octahedron is $4$-regular, and has girth three.  But it is not edge-disjointly covered by $4$-stars (trees with four leaves and one internal node).

Comment: @SamNead Oh, I am really sorry. As you mentioned, I missed a critical hypothesis: $T$ has $k$ edges. Now I revised it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you.  Nice problem!

Comment: Perhaps email Haggkvist and ask him for a copy of the preprint with the proof?

Comment: @SamNead I asked my friend, and he said it would be better to prove a stronger statement: '$G$ is decomposed into copies of $T$, and each $v \in V(G)$ corresponds to different vertex of $n$ copies of $T$.' by induction. I am trying to do this, and considering to mail my graph theory professor. But I think your idea is also nice! Fortunately, I could find his contact from his webpage. Thank you! +) Also, I will answer my question if I get the solution for you and other users.

Comment: I think this question is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256129/any-tree-with-k-edges-t-can-decompose-any-2k-regular-graph-g-into-its-co/4259793#4259793).

Comment: @okw1124 - I believe that caduk's answer (link immediately above) has this property.